# Como posso adicionar Headers a um HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#

Eu estou a usar

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://test.net");
```

para criar uma conexão com o servidor e gostaria de saber como posso adicionar headers ao `httpWebRequest`?

Comment: Qual tipo de paramento, seja bem especifico.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exemplos:

HttpClient:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
          .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

usando webRequest:

```
webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic dchZ2VudDM6cGFdGVzC5zc3dvmQ=");
```

Comment: Desse jeito não funcionou no meu programa .

Comment: ta usando HttpClient?

Comment: Estou usando HttpWebRequest

Comment: atualizei la para webrequest  ve se consegue assim

Comment: Muito obrigado é so esperar mais dois minutos para aceitar a resposta